# How to save image instantly when the user takes a picture (no confirm or retake option)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

**Hello**,
I am trying to create this app with Swift in Xcode that lets the user take a photo with their camera, and then the app sends that photo using http to a server I have set up.

Don't worry about privacy concerns I am not planning on distributing this app anywhere, it is only meant for myself.

When you take a photo using the app the user has to either confirm by using `Use Photo` or retake the photo using `Retake Photo`.

**My question is**, How can we get rid of that confirmation functionality so that the image taken gets saved immediately and can get sent without any option to choose? Is this possible with the standard camera api? I know there's a parameter called didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo that might play a roll in this, and because of that maybe I have to use some 3rd party library to get this to work?
(Most of the code has been written by chatGPT and I don't understand every single part of the code just yet.)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isImagePickerPresented = false
    @State private var capturedImage: UIImage?
    @State private var isCameraAuthorized = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("take another photo") { // This is only if the user wants to take another photo
                isImagePickerPresented.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isImagePickerPresented, onDismiss: {
                
            }) {
                ImagePicker(image: $capturedImage, onImageCapture: { imageData in
                    if let imageData = imageData {
                        uploadImage(imageData: imageData)
                    }
                })
            }
            .onAppear {
                // Display the camera immediately when the view appears
                isImagePickerPresented.toggle()
            }
            
            // Manually send the image to the server. The app should send it automatically after the user confirms.
            Button(action: {
                if let imageData = capturedImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
                    uploadImage(imageData: imageData)
                }
            }) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Cool")
                        .font(.system(size: 70))
                        .padding(69)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 8)
                        )
                }
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(15)
        }
        .background(
            Image("gigachad") // This is just the image for the background of the app
                .scaledToFit()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        )
    }
    
// Here's main
    
    @main
    struct BacknForthApp: App {
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
    
}

//
//  ImagePicker.swift
//  BacknForth
//

import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    var onImageCapture: ((Data?) -> Void)
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.allowsEditing = false

        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        var parent: ImagePicker

        init(parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = uiImage

                
                let imageData = uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
                parent.onImageCapture(imageData)

                
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    parent.onImageCapture(imageData)
                }
            }

            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()  // Dismiss the ImagePicker
        }
    }
}
```

I've mostly just been going back and worth with chatGPT to try and solve this. I think it has something to do with how the api works. The imagePickerController function needs a parameter called didFinishPickingMediawithInfo before the whole thing can work.
To get this to work I might have to use a different library or api because I think I would otherwise have to customize how the library in of itself works, which I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: What have you tried? What isn’t working? It isn’t clear what your end goal is… what API are you trying to change?

Comment: @loremipsum When the user takes a photo and they want to save it, they either have to press "Use Photo" or "Retake Photo". I'm wondering if because didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is a thing if it's possible to get rid of that. So that when the user takes a photo it gets saved and sent instantly without any option to choose.

Comment: @loremipsum I think your most recent comment got deleted or something. Do you know if there's anything in particular that could make this possible or something more specific like some apple documentation I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to handle this might be to manually call `takePicture` on `UIImagePickerController`:

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        var parent: ImagePicker
        private var timer: Timer? // add Timer

        init(parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        // add this function to start the Timer which calls takePicture
        func startCaptureTimer(for picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            timer?.invalidate()
            
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 4, repeats: false, block: { timer in
                picker.takePicture()
            })
        }

    //Coordinator continued...
}
```

Update `makeUIViewController` to hide the default camera controls and call `startCaptureTimer` on the `Coordinator`:

```
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.showsCameraControls = false // hide default controls
        context.coordinator.startCaptureTimer(for: picker) // start capture timer

        return picker
    }
```

This will automatically capture a photo 4 seconds after `ImagePicker` is opened and automatically dismiss without presenting a confirmation. If you still want the user to press a button to capture the photo you will need to set a custom control view on `UIImagePickerController.cameraOverlayView` and have your custom button call `UIImagePickerController.takePicture()`.

Comment: The timer does work. I want the user to press a button but I don't want to use a gui button, I am looking to use the volume buttons on the side of the phone. The JPSVolumeButtonHandler library doesn't seem to work with this. If you see this any ideas?